# Удаление выбранных элементов в ListView из БД

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Необходимо организовать удаление из БД выбранных элементов в `СheckBox`  в `ListView`. Для этого написал такой метод:

```
public void deleteChoose () {
      SparseBooleanArray sba = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
      for (int i = 0; i < sba.size(); i++) {
          if(sba.valueAt(i)){
             db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + sba.keyAt(i), null);
          }
        }
      }
```

По идее, метод должен пробегать по выбранным элементам в listview и удалять их из БД, но он этого не делает. Синтаксических ошибок в методе нет, но есть логические, связанные похоже как с использованием метода SparseBooleanArray так  и с формированием самого запроса к БД. В интернете внятных примеров по связыванию элементов listview с элементами БД как то не нашел, хотя задача довольно распространенная.

Comment: метод `getCheckedItemPositions()` возвращает номер позиции в списке, а не ID записей в БД - это могут быть разные значения. Вам видимо нужен метод `getCheckedItemIds()`. Метод работает только для `ListView` с атрибутом `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: ок, спасибо.. тогда как грамотнее сделать сопоставление номера позиции в списке с ID в БД?

Comment: Вам видимо нужен метод [getCheckedItemIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds()) который возвращает массив long[] с ID чекнутых пунктов

Comment: спасибо, попробую предложенный вами вариант

Comment: спасибо pavlofff, за направление в нужном русле. Действительно переписал  свой метод с использованием getCheckedItemIds() и все заработало как надо